# Use algebra to decide whether a continuous solution exists

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

My problem , put in elementary terms, is: (let $\mathbb{k}$ denote the field of complex numbers, $\mathbb{k}^n$ is endowed with the usual topology)

Let $p_1,p_2,...,p_r \in \mathbb{k}[x_1,...,x_n]$ and denote by $J$ the ideal  they generate. Also denote by $m_0$ the ideal of all polynomials that vanish at $0$.

I need to know that:
$$f_1(0)=c_1,...,f_r(0)=c_r$$

$$p_1(x)f_1(x)+...+p_r(x)f_r(x)=0$$
Admits  a solution $f_1,...,f_r$ of continuous functions iff it admits a solution in polynomials (or put in other words: iff $c_1p_1(x)+...+c_rp_r(x)\in m_0J$)

Less restrictive is the following question:
Consider the following quantity for a set of generators of $J$ : $|J|(x)=|p_1(x)|+...+|p_r(x)|$ (for any other set of generators the obtained norm quantities are equivalent for $x\to 0$). Is it true that the subideal of $J$ of $q(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{|q(x)|}{|J|(x)}=0$ is the same as the subideal of $q\in J$ such that $q^N \in m_0 J^N$ for some $N$.

More generally let $X$ be an affine variety that contains zero.
$$f_1(0)=c_1,...,f_r(0)=c_r$$
$$p_1(x)f_1(x)+...+p_r(x)f_r(x)=0 \, x\in X$$
Admits a solution of continuous functions on X in the subspace topology ( which can be seen as the restriction of continuous functions due to tietze ) iff it admits a solution $f_1,...,f_r \in \mathbb{k}[X] $ ( or put differently $c_1p_1(x)+...+c_rp_r(x)\in m_0J$ in $\mathbb{k}[X]$)

(For example $(x_1+x_2+x_3)f_1+(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1)f_2+x_1x_2x_3f_3=0$ admits no continuous solution unless c_1,c_2,c_3=0, also note that if one of $p_j(0)\neq 0$ then it’s a trivial exercise). I will be content with any other algebraic description given, also is there any reference that addresses these questions.

Answer (score 1):

The second assertion seems to be wrong:
Consider the curve $y^2=x^3+x^2$ which is parametrized by
$(t^2-1,t(t^2-1))$. Take $p_1=x+y,p_2=xy$ and $c_1=0,c_2=1$
.The continuous problem admits a solution
$f_1=\sqrt{x+1}-x-1$ and $f_2=1$ (which makes sense in a neighborhood of $0$) ,but the polynomial problem does not. Though I’m not sure about the first assertion that might be true.